# Can't install BOUT (the book of unwritten tales) on 16.04-64bits

Tags: randr

First, the bout.sh is like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
EXE_NAME=kAGE
BASE_BIN_PATH=./bin
BASE_LIB_PATH=./lib
BITS=32

#run kAGE
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$BASE_LIB_PATH/$BITS/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH $BASE_BIN_PATH/$BITS/$EXE_NAME
```

I fixed a libXaw.so.7 error by installing 32 bits version from [here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/main/base/libxaw7).
So now, trying the bout.sh, I've got this:

```
$ (...)/The.Book.of.Unwritten.Tales$ ./bout.sh
Creating resource group General
Creating resource group Internal
Creating resource group Autodetect
SceneManagerFactory for type 'DefaultSceneManager' registered.
Registering ResourceManager for type Material
Registering ResourceManager for type Mesh
Registering ResourceManager for type Skeleton
MovableObjectFactory for type 'ParticleSystem' registered.
OverlayElementFactory for type Panel registered.
OverlayElementFactory for type BorderPanel registered.
OverlayElementFactory for type TextArea registered.
Registering ResourceManager for type Font
ArchiveFactory for archive type FileSystem registered.
ArchiveFactory for archive type Zip registered.
DDS codec registering
FreeImage version: 3.15.1
This program uses FreeImage, a free, open source image library supporting all common bitmap formats. See http://freeimage.sourceforge.net for details
Supported formats: bmp,ico,jpg,jif,jpeg,jpe,jng,koa,iff,lbm,mng,pbm,pbm,pcd,pcx,pgm,pgm,png,ppm,ppm,ras,tga,targa,tif,tiff,wap,wbmp,wbm,psd,cut,xbm,xpm,gif,hdr,g3,sgi,exr,j2k,j2c,jp2,pfm,pct,pict,pic,3fr,arw,bay,bmq,cap,cine,cr2,crw,cs1,dc2,dcr,drf,dsc,dng,erf,fff,ia,iiq,k25,kc2,kdc,mdc,mef,mos,mrw,nef,nrw,orf,pef,ptx,pxn,qtk,raf,raw,rdc,rw2,rwl,rwz,sr2,srf,sti
Registering ResourceManager for type HighLevelGpuProgram
Registering ResourceManager for type Compositor
MovableObjectFactory for type 'Entity' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'Light' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardSet' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'ManualObject' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardChain' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'RibbonTrail' registered.
Loading library ./lib/32/RenderSystem_GL
Installing plugin: GL RenderSystem
OpenGL Rendering Subsystem created.
X Error of failed request:  BadRRCrtc (invalid Crtc parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  20 (RRGetCrtcInfo)
  Crtc id in failed request: 0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  21
```

I'm tired with this install. All I read for this type of error is old and don't seem to correspond to my case.
What I have to do for this error please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it! I have two screens on this system, one DVI 1280x1024 always ON, and a VGA 1024x728 always off. Using Arandr, I first tried with DVI off , and VGA ON but with "primary" option selected. It works.
So then I tried DVI ON and VGA OFF as always, but I also select "primary" option for DVI: I don't know why but it was not selected before. 
Now the game start fine. 
[edit] I confirm the "primary" option is necessary for this game.